# Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object '' not found

Tags: function, variables

I'm trying to create a simple function as shown below:

```
cleanup <- function(d, j){
  temp0 <- subset(d,!is.na(j))%>%
    group_by(year, j) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
  temp1 <-  aggregate(temp0$n, by=list(Category=temp0$year), FUN=sum) %>% 
    rename(year = Category)
  temp <- temp0 %>%
    left_join(temp1, by=c("year")) %>%
    mutate(pct = (n/x)*100)
  return(temp)
}
temp <- cleanup(d = mydata, j = myvariable)
```

When I call the function, I get an error " Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'myvariable' not found ".

I tried using quotation around myvariable (i.e., "myvariable"), which then gives me "Error: Column `j` is unknown ".

Is there any way to use a variable name within the function?